# Office 365 Exchange Transport Rule to Warn About External Links

Tags: regex, expression, office365, exchange-server

I need help please!

I work for the NHS at a hospital in the UK and we're getting a lot of phishing attacks.  Some are specifically targeted at our domain users - Some people really don't have any morals.

I know staff need to be more vigilant to identify phishing emails, but at the moment they have too many other things to be worrying about with the current COVID-19 pandemic.

I'm trying to create a Transport Rule in Exchange Online (Office 365) to warn the recipient (internal/external) of any email (inbound/outbound/internal) that contains a http/https link that is not within a set of defined domains.

I've figured out a regex expression that works and have given some examples at the following link:
https://regex101.com/r/wkOV4W/3

The expression is:

`https?:\/\/[\w\d\.]*(?<!(CorrectDomain1\.co\.uk))(?<!(CorrectDomain2\.com))(?<!(CorrectDomain3\.org))(\/|\"|\t|\r|\n|\s)`

1. http:// or https://
2. Zero or more subdomains (containing letters, numbers, dots) if any exist
3. Lookback doesn't match CorrectDomain1.co.uk or CorrectDomain2.com or CorrectDomain3.org
4. Next character is a Forward-Slash, Double-Quote, Tab, CR, LF, White-Space

The list of valid domains are:

- CorrectDomain1.co.uk
- CorrectDomain2.com
- CorrectDomain3.org

Any **other** domain or sub-domain should be matched and add a message at the top of the email:

> WARNING: THIS EMAIL CONTAINS A LINK THAT POINTS OUTSIDE OUR ORGANISATION - PLEASE BE CAREFUL IF YOU ARE ASKED TO ENTER A USERNAME OR PASSWORD

When I use this on Exchange, everything works perfectly, apart from one.

This doesn't work: `<a href="http://www.WrongDomainA.co.uk">Link</a>`

This does work: `<a href="http://www.WrongDomainA.co.uk/">Link</a>`, this does work `http://www.WrongDomainA.co.uk`

I know the difference is the slash at the end, but that isn't included in the one where I sent the email in plain text, which worked.

Any thoughts and help on how I can improve this would be greatly appreciated. - I couldn't find a functionality like this in 365 Security & Compliance.

[**Note1**: I should probably include a colon in step 4 to cater for ports]

[**Note2**: I did try combining the domains `(?<!(CorrectDomain1\.co\.uk|CorrectDomain2\.com|CorrectDomain3\.org))`, but it didn't work on the regex101 test because *A lookbehind assertion has to be fixed width*]

[**Note3**: I'm restricted with Exchange because: *You cannot configure a pattern with groups of multiple match conditions like* (.*, *.+, .{0,n} or .{1,n}). Remove the group or the multiple match condition from the pattern to continue.*]

Comment: Maybe you could actually use positive lookahead? `\bhttps?:\/\/(?!(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)*(?:CorrectDomain1\.co\.uk|CorrectDomain2\.com|CorrectDomain3\.org)\b[\/"\s])[^\/"\s]+` (https://regex101.com/r/nPqP33/2)

Comment: Thanks @kishkin, unfortunately, that throws up the error I put in Note 3.  Because within the `?!(` there's a `*`